# Windows XP "Setup is being restarted" loop

Tags: windows-xp, boot

Last night I shut my computer down normally. Today, every time I try to boot it up it displays a blue screen with the Windows XP logo on it saying:

> Setup is being restarted...........

I have tried "Last known good configuration" with the same effect.

- I was not installing anything
- My anti-virus (AVG free) reported that it was off
- I had an audio CD in the drive which I removed today the first time I tried booting up
- I plugged a USB microphone in before turning the PC on

I still have my original XP installation disc and I can get to the XP boot menu. If I try Safe Mode it eventually brings up Windows but says:

> Windows XP Setup cannot run under Safemode. Setup will restart now.
>
> OK

How can I get my computer to boot normally again without losing data (i.e. without reinstalling Windows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspecting that in this case AVG was the culprit (the last four system files loaded in safe mode were for AVG) I went to the AVG site for advice. They recommended making a boot CD or USB stick. Very helpful advice when you only have one computer!

However, they were simply using that to get a command prompt up so I used Windows Recovery Console instead. AVG recommended renaming all `avg*.sys` files to `avg*.old`. I renamed them to `avg*.sys.old` instead (one at a time, unfortunately. I couldn't find a way of batch renaming them without the recovery console saying it was an invalid format for the command). I rebooted the machine and voilà! Windows loaded properly first time!

AVG is now downloading a massive update (90 MB) so I'll watch it carefully to make sure it doesn't play up again!

Comment: Do you have a theory as to why the AVG programs caused this?  Back at the question , was the XP installed really recent, or was it fully installed and rebooted many times , and  on the machine for many days before this occured?  It was the Xp setup that showed error, not some AVG setup items right?

Comment: curious what boot disk they used. do you have a link?  maybe look into an alternative to avg also.

Comment: @Psycogeek Windows XP reinstalled about a year ago on a fresh disc, rebooted many times! It had been on for a couple of days. I suspect some part of AVG failed to install when it updated itself causing Windows to try to install _something_ every time it booted, regardless of whether it was booting normally or in Safe Mode. This would also explain why XP said that AVG was turned off. The only clues I had that it was AVG was the warning message before I turned it off (full shutdown) and the last four sys files shown before going into Safe Mode. Been right as rain since!

Comment: @barlop I was looking on my computer for the link but, of course, my computer wasn't working at the time so it was on my phone! This is the AVG link I was referring to: [Disabling AVG when Windows cannot start](https://support.avg.com/SupportArticleView?l=en_US&urlname=Disabling-AVG-when-Windows-cannot-start). I've been happy with AVG Free for years. I'm not going to change because of a single incident. On the other hand, if it keeps on happening...